# compile error in hidden module mdlReg4x64

Tags: excel, vba

this error raises as soon as I click on  the just installed Excel 2007 -32 bits- ( without any code), windows 11.
( I keep using this version because it has already been installed and works on other PCs,
and does tasks office 365 can't do ).
I checked that the Excel options and the vba references are the same as on my other PCs.

I keep getting the error.
Is there anything wrong in the windows installation? should I try to use the 64 bits version?

Comment: What is in mdlReg4x64?

Comment: If you have any add-ins then disable them all and see if you still have the problem.

Comment: It might need the Excel 2007 Service Pack 3 installing if it's a new install?